# Input value not Updating after setState change... Increment and Decrement

Tags: reactjs, input, setstate

I have these increment and decrement buttons that will add or subtract. I will import the default values from props and then want to allow the user to make adjustments. So when I update the state (series) for the appropriate group it appears to update just fine... but the input value remains '14' in the HTML although I have it set to `value={this.state[mppt_number].series}`. Shouldn't it automatically update when the state changes?

It probably has to do with the [mppt_number] variable.... if mppt_number is =1 when creating the element, wouldn't value be `value={this.state[1].series}`  and `value={this.state[2].series}` for the second time it's created? I don't know... I'm a little new to this.

```
import React from 'react';
//import { defaultValues } from './Calculator';


//Will be passed in as props just have it here for now to ease testing. This can range from 1 to N
const defaultValues = {
    1:{
        array_isc: 10.88,
        array_power: 3834.5999999999995,
        array_vmp: 497,
        array_voc: 584.3312579999999,
        series: 14,
        string: 1,
    },


2: {array_isc: 9.00,
    array_power: 3834.5999999999995,
    array_vmp: 600,
    array_voc: 584.3312579999999,
    series: 12,
    string: 1},
}

const mppt = 2


class Tool extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            stringSizingElement : null, 
        }
        this.handleStringChange =this.handleStringChange.bind(this)
        this.stringSizingElementHelper = this.stringSizingElementHelper.bind(this)

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let s = {};
        for (let i = 1; i <= mppt; i++) {
          s[`${i}`] = defaultValues[i];
        }
    
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ ...s }), () => {
            console.log(this.state);
            this.createStringSizingElementDefaults()
        });
      }


      //Create this element mppt_number of times for each MPPT
    stringSizingElementHelper( mppt_number){
        let stringSizing = (   
            <div className='container' id ={mppt_number} key = {mppt_number}>
                <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <label>MPPT {mppt_number}</label>
                    </div>
                <div className="row justify-content-center" id= {`${mppt_number}`}>
                    <div className="col-4">
                    <label className='container'>Series</label>
                        <div className={`input-group container ${`${mppt_number}`}`} >
                            
                            <button className ='btn btn-primary decrement' onClick={this.handleSeriesChange} >-</button>
                            <input className="form-control series" min="0" name="quantity" value={this.state[mppt_number].series} type="number" disabled/>
                            <button className ='btn btn-primary increment' onClick={this.handleSeriesChange} >+</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>    
        );

        return stringSizing;
    }


    createStringSizingElementDefaults(){
        let temp = []
        //Creating element for each mppt (1:{} , 2: {}) of times for each MPPT This number ranges. 
        for (let i=1 ; i <= mppt ; i++) {
          const  result = this.stringSizingElementHelper(i)
            temp.push(result)
    
        }

        this.setState({stringSizingElement: temp})
    }
    
 
    handleSeriesChange(e){
        if(e.target.classList.contains('decrement')){
            //Get ID to Figure out which MPPT Is being changed
            const mppt_number = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
            var newValues = {...this.state[mppt_number]}
            newValues.series = this.state[mppt_number].series - 1
            this.setState({[mppt_number] : newValues}, ()=>{
                console.log(this.state[mppt_number].series)
            });

        }else if(e.target.classList.contains('increment')){
            const mppt_number = 
           e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
            var newValues = {...this.state[mppt_number]}
            newValues.series = this.state[mppt_number].series + 1
            console.log(newValues.series)
            this.setState({[mppt_number] : newValues}, ()=>{
                console.log(this.state[mppt_number].series)
            })

        }else{
            console.log('Error??')
        }
    }


    render(){

        return(
            <div className="temp container">
                <div className="form-row  justify-content-center">
                    <label htmlFor="sel2"><h4>String Sizing Tool:</h4> 
                    </label>
                </div>
                {this.state.stringSizingElement}
                <br/>
                <br/>
                {undefined}
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Help this girl out? :D

UPDATE:

Didn't store these array of JSX in a state anymore. I create them between render and return now. Now it's not "rendering" when it's stored in a state?  I still get the same results. :(

Now I the function returns the array instead of setting a state.

```
createStringSizingElementDefaults(){
        let temp = []
        //Creating element for each mppt (1:{} , 2: {}) of times for each MPPT This number ranges. 
        for (let i=1 ; i <= mppt ; i++) {
          const  result = this.stringSizingElementHelper(i)
            temp.push(result)
    
        }

        return temp

    }
```

This array is now created in between render and return.

```
render(){
 let stringSizingElement = this.createStringSizingElementDefaults()

 

    return(
        <div className="temp container">
            <div className="form-row  justify-content-center">
                <label htmlFor="sel2"><h4>String Sizing Tool:</h4></label>
            </div>
            {stringSizingElement}
            <br/>
            <br/>
            {undefined}
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

SOLUTION CODE AFTER HELP:

```
import React from 'react';
//import { defaultValues } from './Calculator';
//import './xxxxx.css';

//Will be passed in as props just have it here for now to ease testing
const defaultValues = {
   
     1: {array_isc: 10.88,
        array_power: 3834.5999999999995,
        array_vmp: 497,
        array_voc: 584.3312579999999,
        series: 14,
        string: 1,
    },

    2: {array_isc: 9.00,
        array_power: 3834.5999999999995,
        array_vmp: 600,
        array_voc: 584.3312579999999,
        series: 12,
        string: 1},

    3: {array_isc: 1.00,
            array_power: 3834.5999999999995,
            array_vmp: 600,
            array_voc: 584.3312579999999,
            series: 12,
            string: 1},
}




class Tool extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            
        }
        this.handleStringChange =this.handleStringChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSeriesChange =this.handleSeriesChange.bind(this)
      

    }

    componentDidMount() { 
        let s = {};
        Object.keys(defaultValues).map((mppt_number, i) => (
            s[`${mppt_number}`] = defaultValues[mppt_number]
        ))
    
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ ...s }), () => {
            console.log(this.state);
           
        });
      }





    handleSeriesChange(e){
        if(e.target.classList.contains('decrement')){
            //Get ID to Figure out which MPPT Is being changed

            console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id)
            const mppt_number = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
            var newValues = {...this.state[mppt_number]}
            newValues.series = this.state[mppt_number].series - 1
            this.setState({[mppt_number] : newValues}, ()=>{
                console.log(this.state[mppt_number].series)
            })
            


        }else if(e.target.classList.contains('increment')){
            console.log(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id)
            const mppt_number = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.id
            var newValues = {...this.state[mppt_number]}
            newValues.series = this.state[mppt_number].series + 1
            this.setState({[mppt_number] : newValues}, ()=>{
                console.log(this.state[mppt_number].series)
            })

        }else{
            console.log('Error?? Maybe remove this')
        }

    }


    render(){

     

        return(
            <div className="temp container">
                <div className="form-row  justify-content-center">
                    <label htmlFor="sel2"><h4>String Sizing Tool:</h4></label>
                </div>
                
                {Object.keys(this.state).map((mppt_number, i) => (
                    <div className='container' id ={mppt_number} key = {mppt_number}>
                            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                            <label>MPPT {mppt_number}</label>
                                </div>
                            <div className="row justify-content-center" id= {`${mppt_number}`}>
                                <div className="col-4">
                                <label className='container'>Series</label>
                                    <div className={`input-group container ${`${mppt_number}`}`} >
                                        
                                        <button className ='btn btn-primary decrement' onClick={this.handleSeriesChange} >-</button>
                                        <input className="form-control series" min="0" name="quantity" value={this.state[mppt_number].series} type="number" disabled/>
                                        <button className ='btn btn-primary increment' onClick={this.handleSeriesChange} >+</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                    </div> 
))}
                <br/>
                <br/>
                {undefined}
                <br/>
                <br/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setStste` only overwrites old state in new state, so:

```js
            this.setState({[mppt_number] : newValues}, ()=>{
                console.log(this.state[mppt_number].series)
            })
```

won't update `[mppt_number] : newValues`, but replaces state into `{[mppt_number] : newValues}`. If you want to:

```js
            this.setState((oldState) => ({...oldState, ...{[mppt_number] : newValues}}), ()=>{
                console.log(this.state[mppt_number].series)
            })
```

the above will work. Giving an object as a first parameter of `setState` doesn't cause updating as you intended. Giving a function Instead of an object, working as above.

If you are new to React, and not for using job immediately, I recommend
to use functional components and hooks instead of class method. It's simple and makes outlook of code so good. Try it!

Add:
Problem happens here:

```
        this.setState({stringSizingElement: temp})
```

`temp` contains React nodes and is *rendered as initial state*. `tringSizingElement` in `state` is always rendered nodes, so variables are fixed as constant values.

To avoid this, stop storing nodes into `state`. Nodes in `state` are NOT scope of React DOM rendering, it means they are not updated their variables.

```
    createStringSizingElementDefaults(){
        let temp = []
        for (let i=1 ; i <= mppt ; i++) {
          const  result = this.stringSizingElementHelper(i)
            temp.push(result)
    
        }

        return temp
    }
```

To make `createStringSizingElementDefaults` nodes directly, this problem won't happen.

Add 2:

`this` is a troublesome problem. What `this` points must different what you think. If call `this.func.bind(this)`, `this` in `func` is fixed. In other word, `this.state` is never changed. So even if calling `his.createStringSizingElementDefaults()` over and over again, results are same! To avoid both problems? One of answers is that call `bind` again. But it is not recommended in performance reason. Another is simple. Not to access state in member functions. If you want to, give it as parameters.

And to achieve that, "let view depend on state only" helps you. To decide to make view from state only, doesn't cause to confuse. What this means is following example:

```
class Example extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            somelist: [1, 2, 3],
        }
        this.handleAppend = this.handleAppend.bind(this)
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this)
    }
    handleAppend(){
        this.setState({someList} => {
            let s = [...someList]
            s.push(spmeList[someList.length - 1])
            return {someList: s}
        })
    }
    handleRemove(){
        this.setState({someList} => {
            let s = [...someList]
            s.pop()
            return {someList: s}
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleAppend}>Append</button>
                <button onClick={this.handleRemove}>Remove</button>
                {this.state.someList.map(v => <div>{v}</div>)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

You can confirm that view is decided only state. To change state requires to push button and fire `setState` via `onClick` event. Data flows one-way. This is *IMPORTANT*.

Summarize,

- `setState` takes update function
- Do not include nodes in state
- Do not access `this.state` in member funstions

  - If you want to, give it as parameters
- Keep data flow one-way

If you have a special circumstance, I don't stop to use class-style components, but not, I recommend functional component style strongly.

Comment: I got the same results as I got last time. The console.log is showing it updated in both versions, my old version and your version, but the input element remains value='14'.  The html element value doesn't update. Doesn't reflect the new state.

Comment: I have missed to understand fundamental problem. I will read the code again, just a moment please... But what I said must help you to understand.

Comment: Hi, I no longer store the array of JSX in a state and run the createStringSizingElementDefaults in the render. I updated my original post to clarify. I think that's what you suggested was to not store it in a state?  But I get the same problem. If I did what you suggested wrong, can you give me an example of what you think I should do to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, what I should say was so lacked. I will rewrite the code soon.

Comment: I'll have to lookup what class-style components vs functional component style means. That worked!!! I will update the new code. It's much cleaner too!