# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'getContext' of null

Tags: reactjs, components, mount

In my Application there are 3 pages which are login,register and dash board. when I redirect back to dash board when at login I got this error.
[image: The error]
error is in a component which is called Sensor Reading Chart
**SensorReadingChart.js**

```
class SensorReadingChart extends Component {

    _isMounted = false;
    chartRef = React.createRef();
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        threshold = props.threshold
        xAxisLabel = props.xAxisLabel
        yAxisLabel = props.yAxisLabel
        chartTitle = props.chartTitle
        x = props.x
        y = props.y
        location = props.location
        icon = props.icon
        apiEndPoint = props.apiEndPoint
        yUnit = props.yUnit
        themeColor = props.themeColor

        this.state = {
            sensorReadings:[]
        }
    }

    render() {
        dataPoints = this.state.sensorReadings.map(
            (sensor) => {
                return {
                    x: sensor[x], //change this to proper key
                    y: sensor[y], //change this to proper key
                    location: sensor[location], //change this to proper key
                }
            });
        thresholdLine = this.state.sensorReadings.map(
            (sensor) => {
                return {
                    x: sensor.id, //change this to proper key
                    y: threshold,
                }
            });
        options = {
            type: "line",
            data: {
                xLabels: dataPoints.map(x=>{return x.x}),
                datasets: [
                    {
                        data: dataPoints.map(y=>{return y.y}), //Sample data set [{x:1, y:21},{x:2, y:25},{x:3, y:31},{x:4, y:11},]
                        showLine: true,
                        fill: false,
                        borderColor: themeColor[1],
                        label: yAxisLabel+" Graph",
                        pointBackgroundColor: function(context) {
                            let index = context.dataIndex;
                            let value = context.dataset.data[index];
                            return value > threshold ? themeColor[0] : 'transparent';
                        },
                        pointBorderColor: function(context) {
                            let index = context.dataIndex;
                            let value = context.dataset.data[index];
                            return value > threshold ? themeColor[0] : 'transparent';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: thresholdLine.map(y=>{return y.y}),
                        showLine: true,
                        borderColor: themeColor[0],
                        fill: false,
                        pointBorderColor: "transparent",
                        label: "threshold = "+threshold+" "+yUnit
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 0
                },
                tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                            let label = yAxisLabel+" : "+tooltipItem.yLabel+" F  |  "+xAxisLabel+" : "+tooltipItem.xLabel;


                            if (tooltipItem.yLabel > threshold) {
                                label += "  |  Location : "+data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index].location //change this to proper key

                            }
                            return label;
                        }
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: yAxisLabel + " in " + yUnit,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    xAxes: [
                        {
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: true,
                                labelString: xAxisLabel,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            }
        }

        if(this.state.sensorReadings.length === 0)
        {
            return (<h5 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted " align={"center"}><i className="bi bi-lightning"/>No Readings Yet!</h5>)
        }
        else{
        return (

            <div>
                <div><big><i className={icon} style={{color: themeColor[0]}}/>{chartTitle}</big></div>
                <br/>
                <canvas
                    id="myChart"
                    ref={this.chartRef}
                />
            </div>
        )}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        if(this._isMounted){
        SensorService.getSensorReadings(apiEndPoint).then((response)=>{
            const sensorReadings = response.data
            this.setState({sensorReadings})
            const myChartRef = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");
            new Chart(myChartRef, options);
        });
    }
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        this._isMounted = false;
    }
    

}

export default SensorReadingChart;
```

So I want to regirect to login page without having this error
Here is full error

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'getContext' of null
> (anonymous function)
> src/components/SensorReadingChart.js:154

```
152 |         const sensorReadings = response.data
153 |         this.setState({sensorReadings})
> 154 |         const myChartRef = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");
    | ^  155 |         new Chart(myChartRef, options);
156 |     });
157 | }
```

View compiled
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.  Click the 'X' or hit ESC to dismiss this message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access canvas context in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924150/how-to-access-canvas-context-in-react)

Comment: no that is not the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chartRef = React.createRef();
```

this

```
this.chartRef = React.createRef();
```

---

#### Add

```
...
class SensorReadingChart extends Component {

    _isMounted = false;
    chartRef = React.createRef(); // <-- HERE!!
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
...
```

Basically, JavaScript can't have variables in directly under class like the above, that works unexpectedly. So the line above moves:

```
...
class SensorReadingChart extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._isMounted = false;  // <-- WITH IT!!
        this.chartRef = React.createRef(); // <-- HERE!!
...
```

`this` problem is so troublesome.

---

To avoid `this` problem, I **strongly** recommend functional component style, If you have special circumstance. In functional component style, instance of `this` is always clear.

Comment: I didn't get that

Comment: Ahh, wait! Where does it is also has problem.

Comment: it is in the componentDidMount()

Comment: still have the same issue

Comment: How to write this in functional way?

Comment: I wrote about [hint toward functional way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65365921/input-value-not-updating-after-setstate-change-increment-and-decrement/65366311#65366311), so I'm glad if you read that.